# Responsive background image and it's content

Tags: css, reactjs

I wanted to have a responsive website. But my problem is the background image doesn't resize and it's content misplace when I zoom in or out.

```
<div id="background-image">
  <div>
    /* content here */
  <div>
</div>

CSS:
#background-image {
  background: url("/assets/beautiful-bg.png") no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

What am I lacking in my code?

Answer (score 1):

```
#background-image{
  align-items:center;
  width: 100%; (if not 100vw can be used)
  height: 100%; (if not 100vh can be used)
  background: url('yourpic.png')
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}
```

check this out.

Comment: This seems ok but the content is misplaced

Comment: yes how can I resize the background image and the content at the same time?

Answer (score 1):

You can add '@media' in your css file to get a responsive site.
in styls.css

```
@media (max-width: 1024px) {
  #background-image{
  width: 50%;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to give the parent a height so the image will be properly displayed.

```
#background-image {
   height: 100vh;
   background: url("/assets/beautiful-bg.png") no-repeat;
   background-size: contain /* To resize the image properly with the container*/;
}
```